# Merging Vectors of a and b

Tags: c++, vector, merge

I'm trying to return a vector that combines both vectors of a and b in a manner that if vector a has values of 1,2,3 and vector b has values of 4,5,6,8,9, then the function returns a vector of 1,4,2,5,3,6,7,8,9. So far, I got this code:

```
vector<int> merge(const vector<int>& a,
                   const vector<int>& b){
    vector<int> result;

    size_t aLen = a.size(), bLen = b.size();
    size_t aVal = 0, bVal = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (aLen + bLen); i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0 && aVal < aLen){
            result.push_back(a.at(aVal));
            aVal++;
        }
        else if (bVal < bLen){
            result.push_back(b.at(bVal));
            bVal++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: Do you care if the vectors are sorted before you do this "merge"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where does the 7 come from?  It isn't in the source vectors according to your question.

Comment: The problem is that if I have one vector that has more values than the other(for example, if a holds 1,2,3,4,5,6 and b has 7 it would result in 1,7,2,3,4,5), then I can't get the desired value for the function merge

Comment: PaulMckenzie: no, just merge the numbers like a zipper except the last values that are left out when the last values from the other vector is finished
Jonathan Leffler: that one was a typo, I should've added the 7 in the vector b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking, but if it is just a union of the two vectors, then you can use algorithms to do this:

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iterator>

    using namespace std;

    vector<int> merge(const vector<int>& a,
                      const vector<int>& b)
    {
        vector<int> result;
        std::set_union(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), back_inserter(result));
        return result;
    }
```

See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/

If your goal is to actually interleave the two sorted vectors, then maybe you should choose std::list over vector, and then just call merge().

See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/merge/